# Want to add {{$value['category']}} in <a href="{{route(' HERE ')}}">{{$value['category']}}</a> in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I want to set `{{$value['category']}}` in `{{route('')}}`

This is my code:

```php
@foreach($details as $value)
    <a href="{{route(' **Here** ')}}"> {{$value['category']}}</a>
@endforeach
```

**Controller function:**

```php
public function viewhome(Request $req){
    $product = product::all()->unique('category');
    return view('homepage',['details'=> $product]);}
```

**Route:**

```php
Route::get('/homepage/db_val', 'HomeController@db_val')->name('db_val');
```

How to declare `href` properly. And what will be the route. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) warn : you call `db_val` function in `HomeController` but you show viewhome method in your question.

```
Route::get('/homepage/db_val', 'HomeController@<b>db_val</b>')->name('db_val');
```

if you want use method viewhome :

```
Route::get('/homepage/db_val', 'HomeController@<b>viewhome</b>')->name('db_val');
```

2) **route** is used with named route
   you have a route named 'db_val' --> Route::.... ->name('db_val');
   so it must be used like that ,

```
<a href='{{route('db_val')}}
```

3) in your case , assuming `$value` in `foreach` is an array with a 'category' index inside
   you can use `url` instead `route`

```
@foreach($details as $value)
    <a href="{{url('/your_url')}}/{{$value['category']}}"> 
      link to {{$value['category']}} 
    </a>
@endforeach
```

### 4) but blade spirit  is

route.php

```
Route::get('/showcategory/{id}','HomeController@showcategorie')->name('showcat');
```

view

```
   @foreach($details as $value)
         <a href="{{route('showcat', $value['category'])}}">
    @endforeach
```

it means : you have one named route `/showcategory` with a parameter `/{id}`

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
Route::get('/homepage/db_val_1', 'HomeController@db_val_1')->name('db_val_1');
Route::get('/homepage/db_val_2', 'HomeController@db_val_2')->name('db_val_2');
Route::get('/homepage/db_val_3', 'HomeController@db_val_3')->name('db_val_3');
...
```

Controller Function :

```
public function db_val_1(Request $req){ 
    $all = product::all()->where('category', 'db_val_1');
    return view('homepage', ['details'=> $all]);
}
public function db_val_2(Request $req){ 
    $all = product::all()->where('category', 'db_val_2');
    return view('homepage', ['details'=> $all]);
}
public function db_val_3(Request $req){ 
    $all = product::all()->where('category', 'db_val_3');
    return view('homepage', ['details'=> $all]);
}
...
```

View home: In `route` the value will be `($value->category)` like this.

```
@foreach($details as $value)
    <a href="{{route($value->category)}}"> {{$value['category']}}</a>
@endforeach
```

I got the solution. Thank you for helping.

Comment: If it works for you, it's ok... but it is better using only one route with a parameter... Route::get('/homepage/{dbv}', 'HomeController@db_val')->name('db_val');   in controller you can get {dbv} parameter with public function db_val(Request $request,$dbv) { ... use $dbv... it will be db_val1 or db_val2 or db_valxx or what you put in the url www.xxxx.com/homepage/db_what_you_want , and for url generation use in view : {{ route('db_val') , 'db_what_you_want' }}